# R: Calculate RMS for subset of a group

Tags: r, aggregate, subset

I would like to calculate the RMS of A and B from the following dataset in R:

```
Var Diff
A  -360
A   361
A  -362
B  -500
B  -647
B   700
```

I have found a great post about calculating the mean of a subset using the aggregate function here: 
[R: Calculate means for subset of a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342891/r-calculate-means-for-subset-of-a-group).

Is there a way to use the aggregate function to calculate the RMS of a subset?
If not, then any other approach would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want something like this? `sqrt(mean(abs(Diff)) ** 2)`? That is what do you mean by RMS? What is your expected output?

Comment: Hello, I meant sqrt(mean((Diff)^2)). My expected output would RMS_A=361.001 and RMS_B=621.452.

Comment: Try: `aggregate(Diff ~ Var, data=dataset, function(Diff) {sqrt(mean((Diff)^2))})`

Comment: Thank you GKi, I have posted this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer has been provided by GKi:

`aggregate(Diff ~ Var, data=dataset, function(Diff) {sqrt(mean((Diff)^2))})`